# Pubspec yml in flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, pubspec

[pub speck.ymal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlOw5.jpg)

I have problem in environment it refers environment error may be position is wrong.

Comment: Enter the puspec.yaml file and error message as code. The image is not very visible.

Comment: follow indentation, yaml files are sensitive to indentation. Further read [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/pubspec#:~:text=yaml%20file%2C%20often%20referred%20to,Flutter%20tooling%20needs%20to%20know.)

Answer (score 0):

try to put `sdk: "=2.11.0 <3.0.0"` then do `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`